# Проблема при копировании файлов при сборке контейнера Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

У меня есть проблема при копировании файлов в контейнере.

Есть папка , внутри файл `docker-compose.yml` и папка с сайтом, в папке с сайтом есть `Dockerfile`, где происходит билд.

В `docker-compose.yml` я пытаюсь соединить сайт и `nginx`. С помощью `volumes` добавить эти файлы, чтоб потом можно было их выдавать через `nginx`, но проблема в том, что я что-то делаю не так и файлы не копируются.

Вот так выглядит структура файлов:

[image: файлы]

вот так выглядит `Dockerfile` сайта:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /website
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

вот так выглядит `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3"

services: 
  website:
    build: 
      context: ./media
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ./website/dist:/var/www/

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - website
```

Проблема в том, что после запуска контейнера, папки нет `/var/www/` с html файлами. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @asanisimov добавил фото структуры файлов

Comment: WORKDIR в докерфайле указывает рабочую папку ВНУТРИ контейнера. Попробуйте поменять на /var/www/

Comment: @Nikita поспешил с предыдущей рекомендацией) В вашем контейнере не строится `/var/www`, как выше сказали пропишите в `WORKDIR`, если там должен находиться Ваш проект (не знаю за структуру nodejs приложений). Если там должна какая-то статика лежать/html файлы, то в докере нужно это прописать - создание и копирование туда файлов.

Comment: получается в `docker-compose` `volumes` для `website` не нужен?

Comment: я вообще не вижу у Вас `./website` директории на скрине, и `/var/www/` в контейнере. в `Dockerfile` внутри контейнера Вы объявляете рабочую директорию - `WORKDIR /website` и все файлы копируете туда. У Вас нет директории `/var/www`  в контейнере и `./website` в системе. Что у Вас должно находиться тут - ` папки нет /var/www/ с html файлами` ?

Comment: `depends_on` задает зависимость одного сервиса (контейнера) от другого. А у вас контейнер из образа, который вы создаете своим Dockerfile, вообще не предоставляет никаких сервисов и по факту представляет собой слепок данных сайта. Видимо вам надо было делать его на основе образа nginx.

Comment: Как вы проверяете что нет папки `/var/www/`? И в каком контейнере вы проверяете? Локально на хосте папка `website/dist` существует? Разве ее не команды из Dockerfile создают (`npm build`)? Если она создается именно в Dockerfile то ее не будет существовать на хосте и соответственно она не добавится через volume в контейнер. И последнее, не пытаетесь ли вы в контейнере nginx использовать `/var/www`? Там их точно не будет при текущей конфигурации.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, вы все верно описали. Не подскажите, как в моем случае правильно сделать `docker-compose`?

Comment: Во-первых, есть [две](https://bit.ly/3yGQKGI) причины использовать docker. Вы чего тут пытаетесь достичь? Это для локальной разработки или для запуска на prod-like системе? Подходы отличаются, т.к. в одном случае нужна возможность менять файлы на ходу, а в другом наоборот нужно запретить. Ну и во-вторых, "как сделать в моем случае docker-compose" это слишком общий вопрос, слишком много неизвестных, чтоб ответить однозначно

Comment: @RomanKonoval, в моем случае docker используется для запуска на prod. *Цель*: запуск двух отдельных проектов (бекенд, фронтенд) на одном сервере, одной командой. Для достижения этой цели, был создан файл `docker-compose` с конфигурацией сервера и двумя проектами. В контейнере `website` происходит сборка сайта и создаются файлы, которые мне нужно выдавать пользователю и я пытаюсь перенести их в `nginx` для этого, но понимаю как правильно это сделать и правильный ли у меня вообще подход для достижении этой *цели*.